# Xcode Error Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT Title Set But Using System Identifier

Tags: xcode

[IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/25gto49.png[/IMG]
The title says my error if you are having trouble viewing the image. I have to take snapshots because I do not know when this error message will pop up. This error is not a bug because the exact same error came in a different computer.

Thanks,
Ujjwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question.

For other people experiencing this problem, here's what you do -

1.Select your View Controller

2.Control + Click on your view controller.

3.If you see any yellow or red signs, click on delete.

This worked really well for me.

Hope it helps,

Ujjwal

Comment: Helpful page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb

Answer (score 0):

Please check following checklist.

1. You correct linked to Label in your Storyboard UILabel?
2. Check you used any undefined variables in your Storyboard xib.

Comment: Hi, I have linked everything in my storyboard but sometimes I lose connection for some reason. Do you suggest a way of linking things to your view controller?