# UIAlertController is Crashed (iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller, uialertsheet

I am using Xcode 6 to develop an iOS Application.

When I used `UIAlertController`, it can be worked well on iPhone 6 simulator, but crashes on iPad simulator.

My problem while clicking "share", then it could be crashed.
How could I solve it?

Here is my Code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject] {
    
    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Share", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        
        let shareMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Share using", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        let twitterAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Twitter", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        let facebookAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Facebook", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        let emailAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Email", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        
        shareMenu.addAction(twitterAction)
        shareMenu.addAction(facebookAction)
        shareMenu.addAction(emailAction)
        shareMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        self.presentViewController(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    )
```

Xcode showed this message:

```
******Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController (<UIAlertController: 0xaf71c80>) of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0023c746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c7aa97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   UIKit                               0x012c4062 -[UIPopoverPresentationController presentationTransitionWillBegin] + 3086
    3   UIKit                               0x00bda174 __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke + 1549
    4   UIKit                               0x00bd8247 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 198
    5   UIKit                               0x00c0d31b __40+[UIViewController _scheduleTransition:]_block_invoke + 18
    6   UIKit                               0x00ac6862 ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    7   UIKit                               0x00ac680d _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 415
    8   UIKit                               0x00ac6622 _afterCACommitHandler + 549
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0015d86e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0015d7b0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x001531ea __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00152a5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0015288b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x047b82c9 GSEventRunModal + 192
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x047b8106 GSEventRun + 104
    16  UIKit                               0x00a9c106 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    17  Mars I                              0x0001c724 main + 180
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x02392ac9 start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException******
```

Comment: Apple said that if you want to present any view controller and if its type of AlertViewController then present within popover rather than independent view as its matter related to User Experience.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To keep it device independent, rather use it as shown in the snippet below. This code will return nil for popoverPresentationController on an iPhone / compact size device, so you can safely use it in universal projects.

```
if let popoverPresentationController = shareMenu.popoverPresentationController {
    popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
    popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
}
self.presentViewController(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: just had this issue on iOS10, dont think its fixed

Comment: Actually, you don't need to perform the `if let` check as if the `popoverPresentationController` is `nil` nothing will be set.

Comment: .sourceView should be sender, not self.view in order to display proper arrow direction

Comment: yep, just `popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view` and 
`popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds` will suffice

Comment: What exactly is the `sender` in this case?
Is it the view on which the action was performed?

Comment: Yes, the sender is the UIControl or UIView that fired the action.

Answer (score 41):

try this code:

```
shareMenu.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
shareMenu.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0, 1.0, 1.0)

self.presentViewController(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you explain `CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0, 1.0, 1.0)`?

Comment: @CerlinBoss this defines a 1 pixel square in the middle of the view as to where the menu arrow should point to.

Answer (score 12):

Swift 4

```
popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .init(rawValue: 0)
popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
```

Answer (score 12):

[reference: ActionSheet Popover on iPad in Swift](https://medium.com/@nickmeehan/actionsheet-popover-on-ipad-in-swift-5768dfa82094)

create popoverController :

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Alert message.", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if you want show alert with indicator view should:

```
if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
    popoverController.barButtonItem = sender
}
```

**with indicator**

[image: with indicator]

show alert in center:

```
if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
  popoverController.sourceView = self.view
  popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0) 
}
```

[image: center with indicator]

center no indicator:

```
if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
  popoverController.sourceView = self.view
  popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
  popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
}
```

[image: center no indicator]

Answer (score 7):

I am also face same issue and finally got the solution. 
Here is my solution for Objective-C:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select you option:"
                                                                         message:nil
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@“share”
                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                       // do other things
                                                   }];
[alertController addAction:action];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                     }];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];

// Remove arrow from action sheet.
[alertController.popoverPresentationController setPermittedArrowDirections:0];

//For set action sheet to middle of view.
CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
rect.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width / 20;
rect.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height / 20;
alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = rect;

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: curious why we're dividing by 20 here. I tried 2.0 and that puts it in the bottom right. Something about the geometry is unclear.

Comment: Swift 4 for remove arrow:
`popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .init(rawValue: 0)`

Answer (score 2):

I use this handy extension to create action sheets that never crash

```
extension UIAlertController {

    class func actionSheetWith(title: String?, message: String?, sourceView: UIView?, sourceFrame: CGRect?) -> UIAlertController {
        let actionController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        if actionController.responds(to: #selector(getter: popoverPresentationController)) {
            actionController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView ?? StoryboardHelper.tabBarControllerTopController()?.view
            actionController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sourceFrame ?? CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        }
        return actionController
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code, very easy and understand, maybe i can help for any

```
//if iPhone
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    //if iPad
    else {
        // Change Rect to position Popover
        UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:actionSheet];
        [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this link useful, worked for me

https://medium.com/@nickmeehan/actionsheet-popover-on-ipad-in-swift-5768dfa82094

Made minor changes as below to adjust the alignment.

```
if let popoverPresentationController = alert.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.85, width: 0, height: 0)
        popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = []
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
shareMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
shareMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = 
    CGRect(x: view.bounds.size.width, 
           y: view.bounds.size.height-80, 
           width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
```

source rect is the point from were you want to show popover view.

Answer (score 0):

for **iOS 13**

used it.

```
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if let popoverPresentationController = actionSheet.popoverPresentationController {
                popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
                popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sender.frame
            }
            self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.frame

            actionSheet.show()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need presenting the alert as popover, you can simply use `UIAlertController.Style.alert` as preferred style, when initializing `AlertViewController`.

```
let shareMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Share using", preferredStyle: .alert)
```