# Simple swift Stopwatch don't work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, stopwatch

This is my code.

```
//
    //  ViewController.swift
    //  Stopwatch
    //
    //  Created by Orkun Atasoy on 12.09.15.
    //  Copyright (c) 2015 Orkun Atasoy. All rights reserved.
    //


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerButton: UIButton!

    var timer : NSTimer?
    var ms = 0

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        timerButton.setTitle("Stopp", forState:UIControlState.Normal)

        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    func update() {
        self.ms++
        timerLabel.text = String(self.ms)enter code here
    }



}
```

The Problem is when i run the build it comes the introscreen with big text "Stopwatch" and the it is like freezed there. But it should come a label with button downside which has a text "start". When i click the button it should start counting and the label should change to "stopp". When i click again the it should stop the timer.

I dont get what the Problem ist. I am a Swift newbie. I would be pleased if you could help me.

Thank you for your attention

EDIT >> the label text is at the beginning "00:00".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are messing with `IBOutlet` connections and I have corrected some of your code and here is working code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerButton: UIButton!

    var timer : NSTimer?
    var ms = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        timerLabel.text = "00:00"
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        if timerButton.currentTitle == "Stopp" {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timerButton.setTitle("Start", forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {

            timerButton.setTitle("Stopp", forState:UIControlState.Normal)

            self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    func update() {
        self.ms++
        timerLabel.text = String(self.ms)

    }
}
```

And First of all remove all outlets from your storyboard view controller and connect it this way:

[image]

And if you want check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=45039647649129880048) sample project.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

The method you call when the timer fires is incorrect. From the documentation:

> The selector should have the following signature: timerFireMethod: (including a colon to indicate that the method takes an argument). The timer passes itself as the argument, thus the method would adopt the following pattern:
>   - (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer

So your method should be:

```
func update(timer: NSTimer) {
    self.ms++
    timerLabel.text = String(self.ms)
}
```

And you should set up your timer as:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "update:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

There are a few more things I could mention - such as no need to use `self` when unambigously using variables, and using a dispatch timer instead of an NSTimer, but this should at least solve your immediate problem.

Comment: Yes because that is not the problem.. :)

Comment: it works! I solved it with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb