# Nil error assigning Delegate to PopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem assigning a Delegate to a PopoverPresentationController using Swift 2.2 in Xcode 7.3

Reason of using a Delegate is I'm trying to trigger a function when pressing outside of a Popover view (class RedeemViewController) to go back to the main menu (class MenuViewController). This happens without a button. The function exists in MenuViewController, but it's not relevant what it does now, so I just included the Delegation part where the error occurs.

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

  if (sender as! UIButton == btnRedeem) {
          let rvc = segue.destinationViewController as! RedeemViewController
          let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rvc)
          let popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
          popover!.delegate = self
  }

 }
}
```

Pushing the button btnRedeem, connected to the Segue towards the Popover view, RedeemViewController, leads to

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

In Xcode, the debugger points to

```
popover!.delegate = self
```

The Segue exists and is named in the Storyboard. There are no warnings or obsolete references when right-clicking on the view.

Replacing the code with

```
popover?.delegate = self
```

leads to a more generic error where the debugger stops in AppDelegate:

**libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb) but none of the possible causes applies. I have a generic AppDelegate.swift as described [here](https://gist.github.com/fconcklin/e8ef7d8b056105a04161).

Any help is appreciated! I mostly found examples with buttons but do not want to use a button to exit from the Popover since it's not needed.

Additional info on the Delegation: the function I need running on the background is

**popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController)**

to check when the Popover view (RedeemViewController) is exited and the function I want to trigger within it is one that reveals a new button.

Thank you for reading and maybe you can help me out!

Cheers,

Floris

Answer (score 0):

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: roc)
```

Here you are creating a brand new navigation controller with the root VC as the segue's destination controller. This isn't going to work - the destination controller is going to be set up with whatever container it needs, you don't create new view controllers in prepareForSegue.

You want to look at the `popoverPresentationController` of `rvc`, not of some navigation controller that isn't going to be added to the screen:

```
if (sender as! UIButton == btnRedeem) {
      let rvc = segue.destinationViewController as! RedeemViewController
      let popover = rvc.popoverPresentationController
      popover!.delegate = self
```

}

Comment: Thanks for helping jrturton however I still get
***"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"***
pointing to

`popover!.delegate = self`

Comment: If that's the case then there is no popover presentation controller. Does this view controller actually appear in a popover when you hit that button? Are you working on the right segue?

Comment: The RedeemViewController does actually appear and it's the correct segue. In the if statement it works as well if I state which segue instead of which button so referring to the segue is not the problem. As in:
`if (segue.identifier == "segueToRedeemPopover") {//do stuff}`

The seque is named and has Popover as type.
The RedeemViewController is just an ordinary UIViewController

`class RedeemViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
}`