# When I try to make reloadData() I get a crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I try to reload tableview I get an error like

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

My `UITableViewController`

```
class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var videos = [Video]()
    {
    didSet {

            self.tableView.reloadData() //error here
    }
}
let URL = "https://api.vid.me/channel/1/new"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, self.URL)
        request.responseObject { (response: Response<NewestVideos, NSError>) in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let newest):
            self.videos = newest.videos!
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {return self.videos.count}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewTableViewCell
    let video = videos[indexPath.row]
    cell.newVideoNameLabel?.text = video.completeUrl != nil ? video.completeUrl! : "nil"
     return cell
     }
}
```

I think it's problem with threading? 
In my app I make a .get request and I get a value if I try to print in `didSet` like            `print(self.videos)`
I tried adding

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` error, happens from any ways.

- Remove reference from `outlet`
- Bad name in `performSegueWithIdentifier`
- `IBActions` type.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb) for more info

Comment: There's one more way this error can happen, for me it was when I overlooked something in this call `let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: nil, style: .Cancel) { action in ...` . Even that the `title` parameter is of type `String?` you should not use `nil` (when running Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3 legacy mode). Something is `nil` when in actually shouldn't be. Happy hunting. Since Xcode 8 this error message has been the most confusing to me. The working code for my example is to use an actual `String`: `let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action in ...`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you set `videos`, you are calling it in the `Main Queue`

You can protect `videos` when you set in on `Main Queue`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   self.videos = newest.videos!
}
```

Or you can protect it under:

```
didSet {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: @DmitrievichR Not in get, because you want to reload the data when the var is set (didSet)

Comment: oh not get{} i mean didSet{} but it does not matter i get crash 
now too  when      
`var videos = [Video](){
        didSet {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Then you can check the [jose920405's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39450885/2664437) if you have set the outlet correctly. Check your IB