# subviews userinteraction when superview userinteraction disabled swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I would like to keep subviews (UITextFields in this case) still active (editable in usual way i.e. tap on the textField and a keyboard appears) while the parent view which is a UITableViewCell's userInteractionEnabled is set to false.

Explaining further -
1. There is a UITableViewCell initialized from a xib.

2. Inside this cell, I have three UITextFields and a UIButton.
3. On some condition, I need to disable the cell interaction (to avoid the didSelectRowAtIndexPath) - this part, I do not have any problem.
4. After step 3, all the subViews inside the cell are getting disabled as well.
5. But I need to enter some text inside the textFields and tap the button with some action to it.

What I did so far:
1. Used userInteractionEnabled and set it to false for the cell -

```
myPersonalInfoExpandedCell.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

2. Two textFields firstNameText and lastNameText, I enabled userInteraction and set it firstNameText to becomeFirstResponder

```
 (myPersonalInfoExpandedCell as! PersonalInfoExpandedCell).firstNameText.userInteractionEnabled = true
 (myPersonalInfoExpandedCell as! PersonalInfoExpandedCell).lastNameText.userInteractionEnabled = true
 (myPersonalInfoExpandedCell as! PersonalInfoExpandedCell).firstNameText.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Problem is, for the textFields, the `userInteractionEnabled` is not working which I suspect because of `userInteractionEnabled` is false for the TableViewCell.
The `becomeFirstResponder()` is working for `firstNameText` but I need interaction to all the UI Elements inside the cell.

How can we do that? Please could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the cellSelection implement the willSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method and return nil for the cells that you do not want to select. You say that you want to disable selection under some conditions, so I assume that you have the indexPaths for the rows for which you want to disable selection. Just return nil for these indexPaths. See the following code.

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath == self.MyIndex) //Check for the index path for the cell you want to disable selection for
   return nil;
else
   return indexPath;
}
```

Also do this to prevent the cell from highlighting.

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Doing it this way you do not have to setUserInteractionEnabled:NO on the cell. This way when you tap on the cell the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method won't get called and your textFields would still be enabled

**Edit**

Following is the swift version of the above code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
if (indexPath == self.MyIndex) //Check for the index path for the cell you want to disable selection for
    return nil;
else
    return indexPath;
}


cell.selectionStyle = .None
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shayan! return false for the cells I do not want to select? I didn't get that. Could you quote an example please?

Comment: @LohithKorupolu I have edited my answer. Take a look at it. If you still have questions feel free to ask

Comment: It's working, I am able to edit my textFields but have an issue with my UIButton inside the same view. When I tap the button, I get an exception
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can your provide more log details?

Comment: I only get that single line in my log. I also checked if it's an issue in storyboard or in .swift file (I mean, referencing the Button in my ViewController swift file) but everything looks good

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb
Check out this link. It most probably is a problem with your IBOutlet. Remove all the connections and add them again

Comment: Yeah, I already looked at it. But may be I should remove the connection and re-add them. But for the actual answer, I am accepting it :-)