# Swift AppDelegate crashed

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3

Whenever I import Firebase and do `FIRApp.configure()` in `AppDelegate`, it crashes my app. Moreover, it crashes class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT) and it reports like this:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb).

I haven't worked even with storyboards.

Could you please help me to fix this crash?

Comment: We cant really help you until you provide with more info on your issue :)

Comment: Whenever I import Firebase and FIRApp.configure() into AppDelegate.swift, it crashes my app. Moreover, it crashes class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT) and it reports like this. libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb). Could you please help me to fix this crash? I really need your help. Best Regards,

Comment: Another thing, I want to tell you that I didn't work on Mainstoryboard.

Comment: Post the crash log here. So, that it is easy to check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb). Though the OP is saying it only happens after he imports Firebase. I *personally* think the crash has nothing to do with firebase...

Comment: @Honey So what do u think? Could u tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

- Check whether you have copied GoogleService-Info.plist to the project.
- Also try enabling keychain sharing under capabilities in Xcode.

Comment: I have copied GoogleService-info.plist to the project, but when I downloaded GoogleService-info.plist from Firebase to my computer file name Unknown. This, I renamed it to GoogleService-info.plist and copied to the project. Can it be the problem?

Comment: Is the GoogleService-info.plist readable and structured format.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Answer (score 0):

When you select GoogleService-Info.plist in the Project Navigator, make sure that Target Membership is checked for your target.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to successfully run with FIRApp.configure() in an empty app?

Comment: I know the reason now. First, I downloaded GoogleService-info.plist with unknown file, and I copied to the app and renamed it to GoogleService-info.plist. So it crashes.