# App crashes when presenting view controller

Tags: swift

I modally present a view controller, and then present an activity view controller. However when I do, the app crashes with error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type nsexception ios 10 "self.present"
```

This is what causes the app to crash:

```
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText], applicationActivities: [])


self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I modally present the view controller with just a segue

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showContainer", sender: nil)
```

Comment: Is that the *exact, full* error message?

Comment: you say you use present and then you use perform segue, which one you use and when?

Comment: I guess this answer might be interesting for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27389647/3052525