# Does anyone know why my app crashes when I switch scenes?

Tags: swift, button, sprite-kit, runtime-error, transition

I´m new to coding and I created a game with two scenes(Game Scene and Main menu) with Sprite-Kit. I have a Home Button which switches back to the Main Menu Scene from the Game Scene. When I tapp on the Home Button the app crashes and I wasn´t able to find a solution yet.

Here is the error(occurs while running touchesEnded()):

```
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

    libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x112417d38 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
    0x112417d3d <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x112417d40 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x112417d42 <+10>: jae    0x112417d4c               ; <+20>
    0x112417d44 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x112417d47 <+15>: jmp    0x112410caf               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x112417d4c <+20>: retq   
    0x112417d4d <+21>: nop    
    0x112417d4e <+22>: nop    
    0x112417d4f <+23>: nop
```

This is my code:

```
var homeButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "HomeButton5.0")

class GameScene{

   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

     for touch in touches{

       let locationUser = touch.location(in: self)

     if atPoint(locationUser) == homeButton {

      }
    }
  }

  override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches{

      let locationUser = touch.location(in: self)

       if atPoint(locationUser) == homeButton { // <-- error/ crash 


        let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 0.2)
        let mainMenu = Mainmenu(size: self.size)  

        self.view?.presentScene(mainMenu, transition: transition) //transition
       }
     }
   }
 }


class Mainmenu: SKScene{  //Scene to switch to

}
```

Console:
[image]

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb

Comment: Please format your code properly and use indentation, without indentation it's quite hard to read your code and this is not your first question lacking proper formatting.

Comment: But I´m using Sprite-Kit @AndersSørensen

Comment: try make this with: let homeButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "HomeButton5.0")

Comment: That doesn´t work. @AndersSørensen

Answer (score 0):

You can switch scenes using this code instead.

```
let reveal = SKTransition.flipVertical(withDuration: 0.5)
let gameScene = Game(size: self.size)
self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: reveal)
```

Comment: where does your app crash? at the if statement or inside it? Use print statements to show where

Comment: 'print("1") if atPoint(locationUser) == homeButton { // <-- error/ crash print("2") ... }

Comment: that will show you where the error takes place before or after the if statement

Comment: I get this: 1;
Home Button;
2;
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) @Niall Kehoe

Comment: Show me a screenshot of the console

Comment: Delete all the other print statements and just have the 1 and 2 in the places i said

Comment: I did. @Niall Kehoe

Comment: remove the code for moving to the Mainmenu and see if it still crashes

Comment: Than it doesn´t crashes: @Niall Kehoe

Comment: No, the transition typ is apparently not the problem(crossFade - flipVertical) @Niall Kehoe