# Xcode project keeps crashing after converting to Swift 4, "Class implemented in both..."

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I recently converted an Xcode project to Swift 4. I fixed all the syntax errors. However, my app now crashes, after outputting an error message which starts 

`Class MPExportableArtworkProperties is implemented in both...`

I have been looking around S/O but all I find is that its related to MapBox which I don't even have in my project/podfile. Can it have something to do with the regular map-kit? It crashes the app when I open the tab with my map, so I'm guessing that's where the problem is.

Full error message, formatted for readability:

```
objc[24634]: Class MPExportableArtworkProperties is implemented in both

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaPlaybackCore.framework/MediaPlaybackCore
(0x126b1b108) and

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
(0x1258107d0).

One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
This is the plowerthingscontroller saying that you are logged in
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
NSException
```

Comment: Is it *really* crashing or just writes that in the log?

Comment: its crashing and its the only error message i get so i feel like that have to be why, worked fine util i transformed it to swift 4

Comment: Must read this post [libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27389647/6822622)

Comment: You could play around with the build settings and try and specify one or none of those to link to.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error, and in the end found it was due to something completely different: a circular dependency. Consider:

```
class DependencyManager {

    static let shared = DependencyManager()
    let aDependency: SomeDependency

    init() {

        aDependency = SomeDependency()
    }

    func resolve() -> SomeProtocol {
        // Create the actual class
        return 0
    }
}
```

where `SomeDependency` requires `SomeProtocol`

```
class SomeDependency {

    let x: SomeProtocol

    // Me trying to be clever and auto-inject the dependency
    init(x: SomeProtocol = DependencyManager.shared.resolve()) {
        self.x = x
    }
}
```

So when you first access `DependencyManager.shared` it tries instantiate `SomeDependency`, which requires `DependencyManager.shared` to already be instantiated.

I have no idea why `MPExportableArtworkProperties` is mentioned in the error, however cleaning up the code fixed the issue for me.