# iOS app crash when call dismiss method

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

From an UIViewController embebed in a UITabBarController I perform a modal segue by

```
self.present(.....
```

being "self" my view controller inside my UITabBarController. The new ViewController shows perfectly, let's call it `ViewController2` that it's presented by `ViewController1` modally. If I try to dismiss `ViewController2` it always crashes with an Unknown Exception. `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.
ViewController2` is embebed in a `UINavigationController` but this `ViewController2` is the only one that crashes.

I've tried dismissing the `presentingViewController`, `presentationController`, `presentedViewController` and `self.navigationController?.dismiss` but nothing is working for me.

The architecture is: `UITabBarController->ViewController1 -modally present- UINavigationController->ViewController2`

This is my presenting code:

```
guard let vcDetail = UIStoryboard(name: "ProjectDetailStoryBoard\(currentDevice)", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcDetailProject") as? ProjectDetailController else{return}
    vcDetail.instantiatedFromPushNotification = true
    vcDetail.projectId = key

    let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vcDetail)

    UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And this my dismissal code:

```
@IBAction func dismissView(){

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: "it always crashes with an Unknown Exception": Do you ming showing the whole error message?

Comment: Sure. I've updated the OP.

Comment: Is that the full error message? Don't you have more before with the stacktrace and more info about that exception? If you look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb that's the whole error message with all clues.

Comment: Post your present and dismiss code.

Comment: Updated with present and dismiss code