# Getting error while using google maps and error is - libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

I have create new mapViewController.swift file and its xib file also. In mapViewController i have import googlemaps and googleplace

I have create a new uiview and define its class as GMSMapView.
I have also add IBOutlet like this -> `@IBOutlet weak var showMapView: GMSMapView!`

This is my view in which i have add uiview define its class GMSMapView
[image]

And i use this code to show google map

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 53.9,longitude: 27.5667, zoom: 6)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: showMapView.frame, camera: camera)
showMapView = mapView
```

Check i have attach screen shot of my code with breakpoint and i step over by one
[image]
This is next screen shot when i step over by one but when i again step over step then my app will crash and error as i mention below:
[image]
and i have add break point on `GMSCAmeraPosition` then i increase breakpoint line by line when i cross `GMSMapView.map` then i app will crash
and got error in my console is libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Could you show the WHOLE error message? From the part with "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'" (note the "***", the uppercase at "Terminating" and the "NSUnknownKeyException" instead of "NSException". to the one you give us.

Comment: I am only get this error -> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException. No more error and i have also integrate google places auto complete on another view controller that's working fine...

Comment: You don't have more messages like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb ?

Comment: No i didn't get any other error message as mention in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb

Comment: try adding Exception Breakpoint in Navigator view.

Answer (score 0):

I have unchecked "run script only when installing" from build phases under "copy pod resources"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er4y9.png)