# FBAudienceNetwork throws libc++abi.dylib exception in iOS project

Tags: ios, ads

I have used FBAudienceNetwork using pod and it's install FBAudienceNetwork (5.0.0) version.

but app is always crashing before going to my demo viewController file and gives below crash detail.

```
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: did you check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb

Comment: Yes, it is fine. no wrong outlets or action in storyboard.