# iOS app crashes when closing with NSException

Tags: swift, crash, ios-simulator, device, nsexception

I had a working iOS app with Jukebox music library and background audio. However, an hour after everything was working well, the app started to crash with

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

every time I close the app. Usually the music used to continue playing in the background, but now the app crashes. I also opened an old project that was only working well, but the same error came up.

The app works well in the simulator, but not on the device.

[image]

[image]

I didn't post any code because I literally didn't change things in the old project at least for it not to work anymore and crash. What should I do? The outlets are good btw.

---

EDIT

Here's the stack trace:

[image]

What's weird is that I tried the app on my friend's iPhone 6 running 12.1 and it worked with no issue, however when I do it on my iPhone 6S running 12.1 it crashes. What do I do in this case?

Comment: You should try to find out what that nsexception is ;)

Comment: @Mars Can you please help me? it’s really annoying that my app suddenly stopped working. I added the exception breakpoints, but they didn’t help as it directly points to AppDelegate when the crash occurs

Comment: You need to show a stack trace or error message

Comment: But secondly, try googling the error message. I see a ton of possible solutions/causes HERE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb

Comment: @Mars I added the stack trace. Another thing is that the app worked on my friend's iPhone, but not mine. How is that? I did a lot of research before asking the question on SO so i've seen the link you're re-directing me to