# libc+abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsexception

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {  
        let alert = SCLAlertView()  
        alert.addButton("A",target:self,selector: #selector(FirstViewController.firstButton))  
        alert.addButton("B",target:self,selector: #selector(FirstViewController.secondButton))  
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {  
            alert.showSuccess(kSuccessTitle,subTitle: kSubtitle1)  
//            self.present(secondViewController,animated: true,completion: nil)  
        })  
    }  
    @objc func firstButton(info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])  
    {  
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle: Bundle.main)  
        let secondViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "view2") as! SecondViewController  
        secondViewController.infoFromViewOne = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage  
        secondViewController.flag = 0  
        self.present(secondViewController,animated: true,completion: nil)  
    }  
    @objc func secondButton()  
    {  
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle: Bundle.main)  
        let thirdViewcontroller = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! ViewController  
        self.present(thirdViewcontroller,animated: true,completion: nil)  
    }
```

This is my code,
My desire result is that when I click the first button, the page jump to "SecondViewcontroller" and the image in the SecondViewcontroller's imageView is the photo I just select.

But now, after selecting the photo and click the first button, the app crashes at AppDelegate.swift, with an error message:
"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type `NSException`"

What should I do to make it correct?

Comment: was there any other error in the console as well? i belive their must be another line of description as well.

Comment: Share the complete crash report i.e. right after _NSException_

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed Nope,There is just a line error at console

Comment: show me the declaration of this "infoFromViewOne " vaiable

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi I'm sure there was no error message after that.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed var infoFromViewOne:UIImage?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb

Comment: @Anand Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score -2):

```
private var infoFromViewOne: UIImage()
    var _infoFromViewOne:UIImage {
    set{ 
         _infoFromViewOne = newValue 
    }
    get{ 
         return _infoFromViewOne
    }
}
```

replace it with this remove error if because I don't have that exact code snippet right now but maybe can provide you tomorrow.

Comment: Answers are more helpful if they *explain* the problem and the solution.

Comment: I added these code and there are something wrong:1.Invalid redeclaration of 'infoFromViewOne' 2.Attempting to modify '_infoFromViewOne' within its own setter 3.Attempting to access '_infoFromViewOne' within its own getter