# Getting black screen with "uncaught exception of type NSException" error in production build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

My React Native iOS app works in development mode but crash in release mode.

Here is my [React-Native App Info](https://gist.github.com/cyb3rsalih/4b61f0863d3febfba6ed6e3bcca87e20)

I tried
    - Clean build
    - Re-install watch-man (suggested in another question)
    - Re-install node-modules file

After splash screen, app stuck at black screen.
  The Xcode screen give me [this information](https://gist.github.com/cyb3rsalih/2177b824576e7ffdaa2616a2ca5d30ec)  during the crash with this code screen.

The line with Thread 5... is marked from xcode with this alert.

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x205af60d4 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x148
    0x205af60d8 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x205af60dc <+8>:  b.lo   0x205af60f4               ; <+32> //Thread 5: signal SIGABRT
    0x205af60e0 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x205af60e4 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x205af60e8 <+20>: bl     0x205aeba3c               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x205af60ec <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x205af60f0 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x205af60f4 <+32>: ret
```

I expected to app will work like development but it shows black screen after splash screen. For keep question short, I create links for errors and informations.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try killing possible old packager instances in your Terminal windows as suggested in the Xcode output? Just to be sure, maybe quit Terminal, and run `npm start` (or `yarn start`) again before starting the application.

Comment: Yes I tried. It freezes in splash screen this time.

Comment: After disconnect from mac,  splash screen > black screen > closing

Comment: you can try solutions from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb