# How to enable Xcode debug messages

Tags: ios, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b15cZ.png)
I am trying to debug my app after crashing but the console gives me no other info but

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

how do I enable the debug messages?

Comment: That should be the only thing Xcode tells you. It also should highlight a line of code in your program. Does it do this?

Comment: highlights class: Appdelegate, I disable something awhile ago but I wasn't really sure what it was but I used to get a lot more info on crashes some like "call to stack xxxxx"

Comment: Can you post the whole console? There should be a spot where a line number is given...(for example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb))

Comment: Yeah I'm missing all the stuff that's in that link

Comment: Have you modified something in the projects settings? Like changing the name of the MainStoryboard or the LaunchScreen?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling a break point on All Exceptions. Maybe you can see where the throw is coming from and debug from there.

ps. CoreData has terrible error reporting.

Steps:

1. Go to the breakpoint tab in the left navigator.
2. Hit the plus button on the bottom left and click Exception Breakpoint.
3. Make sure Exception is set to `All` and Break is set to `On Throw`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Breakpoint navigator and add a breakpoint for `All Exceptions`.

The app should then stop at the line that causes the exception.

[image]