# UINavigationController push crash

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a NestedViewController which I am trying to push into a UINavigationController. This causes a crash with a following stack trace:

[image]

Additionally:

- All of this is happening on the main thread
- This reproduces both on iOS 11 and 12
- `animated` flag doesn't change anything
- NestedViewController gets modally presented somewhere else in the app and it does so successfully, without crashing
- NestedViewController gets its layout from a storyboard
- NestedViewController with its view initialized programmatically and identical to storyboards layout still causes a crash
- Pushing an empty UIViewController doesn't cause a crash

What am I doing wrong?

UPD1: I made this yet this doesn't cause a crash:

```swift
let controlla = { () -> UIViewController in
    let cont = UIViewController()
    cont.view = {
        let view = UIView()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [ {
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

            view.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.height.equalTo(128)
            }
            return view
        }() ])
        view.addSubview(stack)

        stack.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        }

        return view
    }()
    return cont
}()

controller.pushViewController(controlla, animated: true)
```

UPD2: On the request of user Adeel in the comment here is what it says in the console upon an abort breakpoint hit:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

If it was so simple and the message was there, this question wouldn't really exist, would it.

UPD3: So to extend my investigation I have uninstalled all of the views inside the view controller except for the root one.

[image]

The scene tree, while at it, started to look like this:

[image]

Then, of course, I got rid of all outlets and the code that was in the view controller.

**It still crashes. The modal present still works fine though.**

UPD4: I renamed the NestedViewController into some other name just in case. Didn't work.

UPD5: Before UPD1 it looked like this:

```
controller.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Comment: Instead of posting an image can you please share entire crash log? Specially the line where it says "terminating app due to uncaught exception" (if that exists).

Comment: @Adeel alright, posted it in the UPD2 section of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in UPD5, the controller you are pushing into the navigation controller is literally that same controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb)

The crash info is obscure. Hope it can inspire you.

Comment: Nope, this statement is unfortunately invalid. Missing outlets always result in an unrecognized key exception while trying to KVC, usually in `-[NSObject+ (NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:]`, which gets called in a course of `-[UIViewController loadView]`. This method might be called both before and after a modal presentation/nav controller push and thus this failure is independent of view controllers state.

Comment: Spoiler: I know this for certain because I just happen to have a crash log where this exact case happened, unrelated to the flow in question.

Comment: No idea. Check this and maybe it can inspire you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb