# Sudden MGLMapView WARNING in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I've been working on an iOS app for the last 2 months and this morning suddenly the app started crashing when pressing the Map button to load the mapView.

Initially I thought maybe I caused it, but I went to an older build and the problem was still there.

Looking at the debugger:
MGLMapView WARNING UIViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is deprecated use MGLMapView.automaticallyAdjustContentInset instead.

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::domain_error
(lldb)

Can anyone shed any light on how to get past this? I keep thinking maybe mapbox changed something, or apple changed something, but somehow I don't think that's the case.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Mapbox are you using? Latest is 5.8.0.

Comment: Using the latest, Mapbox 5.8.0

Comment: The warning about deprecation is very unlikely to be the cause of the crash. Have look at some of the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb

Comment: Thank you for the link Magnas. I am running through the possible scenarios, but one thing that stuck, is that the installed build was running okay for about a week. No issues. And halfway through the day today, it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

So after following Magnas' post (thank you) and doing some more error log digging, found the issue!!!

Whilst loading the map viewer, I was parsing a json file for my markers to be displayed. Apparently one marker wasn't added properly in my SQL and it was crashing during parse.